# Data for a classification task with two classes

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, dataset, classification, supervised-learning

As I am still learning, I am implementing a neural network for a two-class problem. Let’s call the classes class A and class B. Before training, the first thing I do is to collect data from both classes, and then shuffle it. Now, I am aware of how to split data into multiple sets (training, validation, and test).
My question is about what the data actually should contain. If we seek to find out that new and unseen data belong to class A, and if we view the data that belongs to class A as a positive class, and if we view all of the rest data as a negative, should the negative data really contain a collection of different classes such as B, C, D, etc.?

If we talk percentages, then my question is if, say, 50% of the data should belong to class A (positive), while the remaining 50% should be e.g. 33% B, 33% C, and 33%D (which all are negative)?

So basically I have multiple classes, A, B, C, D, and so on. But I only seek to find out if something is class A or not. Is this why it is still considered a two-class problem (positive/negative) even though I actually use several classes? As you probably understand, I'm quite confused.

Comment: why don't you simply relabel all your B, C, D classes as NON-A or something? You could train a multi-class classifier to distinguish among all the classes, but since you care about one decision boundary only, I would preprocess the data so that they reflect the problem you are interested in.

Comment: @SheepPerplexed that is an idea! But do I really need to have multiple classes that represent the negative? Would it not be enough with just 50% A and 50% B mixed up?

Comment: That is what I was trying to say :)

Comment: Thanks @SheepPerplexed , but do you know if one approach has an advantage over the other? 
Is there even any benefit of allowing the other half, which represents the negative class, to consist of several other classes, B, C, D, etc. (Which is renamed to, for example, Non-A)?

Comment: In case you are really interested in the binary problem only, i.e. A vs Non-A, I don't believe a multi-class classifier is the way to go. You should change your data so that they reflect two classes and train a binary one.

Comment: I'd recommend using scikit-learn's dataset for learning purposes. The Iris dataset is a good classification example where you can see the distribution of labels, the features and training/test partitions. You can find it [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/datasets/). Also you can work with their digit classification dataset after Iris.